# MongoDB performance: newsfeed architecture, subscribers, comments

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, feed

I use MongoDB + PHP for a "facebookish" newsfeed with different kinds of feeds (post, photo, poll, etc.) and with  comments.

Each feed belongs to some "channel" - currently it could be *user* or *group* (there may be more containers in future).

Any user can subscribe for any channel or unsibscribe from it.

Now let's say there're tons of channels and tons of feeds. What is the best structure for channels/feeds/comments?

I'm thinking about two approaches:

**1) Feeds collection with list of subscribers in each feed:**

```
feeds: 
[
   {date_added: ..., 
    last_update: ..., 
    title: ...,
    text: ...,
    channel: ..., 
    channel_subscribers: [...],
    comments_subscribers: [...],
    comments: [...] 

   },
   {...},
   {...},
   {...}
]
```

If I want to get last feeds:

```
db.feeds.find({date_added: "this week", channel_subscribers: "my_login"});
```

If I want to get feeds with new comments:

```
db.feeds.find({last_update: "this week", comments_subscribers: "my_login"});
```

*Pros:*

- Simple and fast readings?

*Cons:*

- When I want to subscribe/unsibscribe for/from a channel, I have to run
  trough all feeds and push/pull my name from list of
  channel_subscribers; it could be slow if I have tons of feeds

**2) Separate "channels" collection:**
Same thing but keep list of subscribers in channel collection:

```
channels: 
[
  {channel_id:..., last_update: ..., subscribers: [...]},
  {channel_id:..., last_update: ..., subscribers: [...]}
]
```

First I have to query last updated channels:

```
subscribes = db.channels.find({last_update: "today", subscribers: "my_login"})
```

Now find my feeds:

```
db.feeds.find({channel: {$in: subscribes}], date_added: "today"})
```

*Pros:*

- Simple, fast and more safe subscribing/unsubsribing;

*Cons:*

- I feel I should avoid **$in** because it's slow(?), especially when I have lots of
  subscribes to put inside of this operator.

**3) Keep user subscribes in users collection (so each user has an array of his own subscribes)**

```
users:
[
  {_id: ..., login: ..., email: ..., subscribes: [...]}
]
```

*Cons:*
- in this case we'll have even bigger array to put inside of $in than in previous (#2) approach.

**4) Your suggestions?**

Comment: MongoDB recommends that they data structure you use is geared toward your most common use case. Still having a bit of difficulty understanding your current structure though. Can you elaborate on your structure a bit more?

Comment: OK let me simplify my question. What would be faster: keep a list of my subscribes and then put that big array inside of "$in" operator and get my feeds by that; OR - get feeds by my login name - when every feed has a big (~2000) array of subscribers in it? (is it good practise to create multikey index on such big arrays?)

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to keep the subscribers in the feeds itself. Might be better to link them. This looks a bit SQLey, but it makes for easy searching and removal as well.

Comment: thanks! I think I'll better make a speed test for both cases and post results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'll answer by myself. I tried to make a test on my laptop Windows 7 32 bit / 2GB RAM.
I created a "feeds" collection and filled it with 500 feeds:

```
feeds:
[
 {_id: ..., subscribers: [...]},
 {_id: ..., subscribers: [...]},
]
```

Each "subscribers" array have a list of 2000 short random string names.

First I have to mention that my DB increased in size from 60Mb to 1.5Gb.

Then when I run a shell command `db.feeds.ensureIndex({subscribers: 1})` it hanged for ~3 minutes and then stopped with error: `"can't map file memory - mongo requires 64 bit build for larger datasets"`.

So it's definately not a good idea to create such large multikey fields inside of mongo's documents.

Comment: Just a note, the 32bit mongo version has a [hard limit of 2GB for the data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations) . In any case though, it definitely makes sense for you to have it separate so that referencing is faster and easier. Since you'd want to link to user objects rather than just strings.